# particles.js как задний фон

Tags: html, css

Хотел для своего проекта сделать верстку страницы, но не особо знаком с такими свойствами css, как position или flex и прочее (работаю php разработчиком, поэтому не приходится с этим сталкиваться). Хочу разместить готовую библиотеку particles.js на задний фон за Masonry, но выходит криво. Я разместил в codepen то, что у меня получилось, но появилась проблема. На адаптивности (например iphone6/7/8) particles не отображается в полную высоту, на задний фон вроде как получилось засунуть. Прошу помочь с этим. Задний фон нужно разместить в секции новостей, что соответствует свойству container-fluid. После этого контейнера находится футер и до этого контейнера swiper, поэтому как задний фон нужно разместить только внутри этого контейнера.
Вот что я наверстал: https://codepen.io/4haz/pen/VwboVEw
Подключены: bootstrap 4, masonry, particles.js, jquery.
Конфиг для particles я не смог загрузить в этот sandbox, поэтому приложу его здесь:

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": false
}
```

Comment: Я бы сначала поместил на передний фон, а затем сделал бы его задним.

Comment: @yar85 извини, не особо понял, каким образом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поправьте стиль particles только уберите красный цвет

```css
#particles-js {
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

Comment: Я пробовал вариант с position: fixed, но у меня сверху в шапке находится swiper-container, который также имеет свои z-indexы, поэтому у меня необходимость отображать его только внутри контейнера, если использовать этот вариант, то получается так: https://ibb.co/y85Yrdq

Comment: Так добавить z-index  по слоям